Laravel Nova select field option disable
I want to disable only one option from select list, how I can do it?
Select::make('Cloudflare', 'cloudflareId')
            ->searchable()
            ->options($allCloudflares)
            ->onlyOnForms();


Please clarify that based on which condition you want to disable that option from select list ?

for example, if something = 1 then $allCloudflares[option1] disabled

It's a hacky solution, but might work in your case.
Let's imagine that your $allCloudflares array looks like this:
$allCloudflares = [
   'cloudflare1',
   'cloudflare2',
   'cloudflare3',
];

You could use a custom function inside the options() method of a select like this:
Select::make('Cloudflare', 'cloudflareId')->options(function (){
    $items = [];
    foreach ($allCloudflares as $cloudflare){
        //Your condition
        if($cloudflare == 'cloudflare2'){
            $items[$cloudflare] = ['label' => $cloudflare, 'disabled' => true];
        }else{
            $items[$cloudflare]  = ['label' => $cloudflare];
        }
    }

    return $items;
}),

In this case, generated select will look like this:

As you can see, option 2 is disabled.
Edit: Update for searchable()
Unfortunately, searchable() in Laravel Nova doesn't support disabled attribute. However, as a fallback, you could use rules() method, and prevent user from submitting the form if they select an option that should be disabled:
->rules(function () {
    return [
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if ($value === 'cloudflare2') {
                $fail('This option is disabled.');
            }
        },
    ];
}) 

When selecting the option, and submitting the form, you will be presented with the following:


Hi, thanks, good solution. But it not work with ->searchable()

@MaksimRiabchenko I updated my original answer with more info regarding searchable()

very thanks a lot!

Glad I could help! If the answer helped you in any way, mark it, so others can find it and solve similar issues :)

The other thing you could do is filter out the invalid options:
->options(collect($allCloudflares)->only($validOptionsKeysArray)->all())
